# Spring OAuth2 security and ResourceServer configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-oauth2

In my Spring Boot application I have configured following ResourceServer:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private ResourceServerTokenServices tokenService;

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        // @formatter:off
        resources           
            .resourceId(RESOURCE_ID)
            .tokenServices(tokenService);
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http                
            .antMatcher("/api/**")
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS);
        // @formatter:on
    }

}
```

The problem is that some of my API endpoints must be not secured but according to this configuration everything is secured under the `/api/**` path.

For example I have a following API endpoint:

```
POST /api/v1.0/users/create
```

that can be accessed anonymously.

How to configure this ?

Also, is it possible to override security rules described in `ResourceServerConfiguration.configure` method with annotations, for example with `@PreAuthorize("permitAll()")`:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1.0/users")
public class UsersController {

    @PreAuthorize("permitAll()")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public UserResponse create(@RequestBody CreateUserRequest userRequest) {
        ...
    }

}
```

May be I'm doing something wrong but unfortunately it doesn't work right now.

**UPDATED**

As suggested below I have added new `antMatcher` to `ResourceServerConfiguration`:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // @formatter:off
    http                
        .antMatcher("/api/v1.0/users/create").anonymous().and()
        .antMatcher("/api/**")
        .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS);
    // @formatter:on
}
```

This is also my `WebSecurityConfig`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private SocialAuthenticationSuccessHandler socialAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    private DBUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Value("${social.postLogin.url}")
    private String postLoginUrl;

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        // Spring Security ignores request to static resources such as CSS or JS
        // files.
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/static/**");
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        // @formatter:off
        http.addFilterBefore(new CorsFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class);

        // Set a custom successHandler on the SocialAuthenticationFilter
        final SpringSocialConfigurer socialConfigurer = new SpringSocialConfigurer();
        socialConfigurer.addObjectPostProcessor(new ObjectPostProcessor<SocialAuthenticationFilter>() {
            @Override
            public <O extends SocialAuthenticationFilter> O postProcess(O socialAuthenticationFilter) {
                socialAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(socialAuthenticationSuccessHandler);
                socialAuthenticationFilter.setPostLoginUrl(postLoginUrl);
                return socialAuthenticationFilter;
            }
        });

        http
            .csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/api/**")
            //.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()

            .antMatchers("/oauth/authorize").authenticated()
            //Anyone can access the urls
            .antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/actuator/health").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/actuator/**").hasAuthority("PERMISSION_READ_ACTUATOR_DATA")
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .permitAll()
        //Adds the SocialAuthenticationFilter to Spring Security's filter chain.
        .and()
            // apply the configuration from the socialConfigurer (adds the SocialAuthenticationFilter)
            .apply(socialConfigurer);
        // @formatter:on
    }

    /**
     * Configures the authentication manager bean which processes authentication
     * requests.
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

}
```

I still receive `AccessDeniedException` exception:

```
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:124)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:176)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add another `antMatcher` for the anonymous path and permin all roles (including anonymous).

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // @formatter:off
    http
            .antMatcher("/api/**").authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/v1.0/users").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS); 
    // @formatter:on
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately still doesn't work. I have updated my question with more details.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was too quick on this:). I've updated the answer, this time I've tried it myself locally.

Comment: Thanks, now it is working fine. Right now I'm a little bit concerned about the configuration when I need two different access models for GET /api/v1.0/users and POST /api/v1.0/users  .. For example the first one should be secured and the second one public.. How to extend the current configuration in order to support this ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, well, in such a scenario you'll need to handle access control on a the controller level. Can't really come up with example right now:(